# How to texture paint this image onto a mirror object?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, uv, texture-painting, mirror

I am having trouble texture painting my image onto my object because the object is mirrored- so when I paint onto it, the texture is therefore also mirrored.
I've tried applying the mirror modifer, but it makes no difference.

Does anybody know the fix for this? Thanks.[image]

Comment: Once you have applied the modifier, you probably need to check your UV a second time, because the duplicated side from the mirror will also duplicate and overlap the "initial" UV

Comment: @B.Pader Thank you so much! It worked!

Comment: I will add it as an answer if other people need this info

Answer (score 1):

Once the modifier is applied, check the UV.
UVs from the duplicated side will overlap the "initial" UVs.